# Matlab UI program works unproperly after deploytool

Tags: linux, windows, matlab, compilation

this is the first time I'm encountering this kind of issue.
I have a perfectly working code that runs without any issue under 3 different platforms (Win/Linux/OS X).
However after the deploytool compilation a part of it stops working. How can I get the error once the code is compiled!? It seems that it has some problems in loading and reading .mat files. Is that possible?
I hope someone can help me.

Thanks

edit:
I've solved the problem! Unfortunately was all addpath fault!
I have a lot of folders with files and functions that are needed for running the code, after the compilation matlab does a mess with all of that folders. 
Good hint: do not use addpath for the compilation! Thank you anyway!

Comment: I was indeed wrong about the project settings and edited my post. Could you be a bit more specific in what exactly goes wrong and whether you still think it is related to loading .mat files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `try` to `catch` the error and write it to a text file. Or build in a check that prints text to the screen.

A bit more in general: You can try to isolate the part of the code that has the problem, and then basically cut out half of the functionality in this part repeatedly until you have exactly found the source of the error.

Comment: doen't seem to me that the project settigs are much modifiable. Just the toolboxes and MCR inclusion... I don't have any error return in the command prompt after the compilation. The weird part is that it gives me the idea that the operation has been successful! :(

Comment: the problem is related to a uitable update part of the code. The user can change the rows and edit them, but after the compilation it doen't work properly. :( :(